# Place div over 2 other divs, unknown content - CSS only

Tags: html, css

I want to stack a div over 2 other divs, all 3 with unknown content, so the padding bottom of 1 and padding top of 3 should not be hardcoded. Is there any CSS-only solution for this?

```css
.stacked {
  color: #fff
}

.stacked .first,
.stacked .third {
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 20px
}

.stacked .first {
  background: red;
  padding-bottom: 100px
}

.stacked .third {
  background: blue;
  padding-top: 100px
}

.stacked .second {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 50%;
  position: relative
}

.stacked .second>div {
  background: green;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="stacked">
  <div class="first">
    Unknown content - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nisi arcu, convallis sed luctus in, volutpat luctus magna. Cras facilisis odio sed sem maximus ullamcorper. Donec laoreet vulputate suscipit. Proin rutrum elit eu dui ultricies
    auctor sit amet pharetra tortor. Donec feugiat iaculis ex id cursus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Donec viverra dolor eget ligula semper vestibulum. Phasellus dictum nulla quis lectus congue,
    sit amet pulvinar neque volutpat. Duis finibus sapien quis lorem suscipit, et luctus erat rutrum. Integer accumsan ipsum nec felis ultrices finibus. Integer at tincidunt orci. In tempus sollicitudin velit, sed dignissim ligula maximus ac.
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <div>
      Unknown content - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nisi arcu, convallis sed luctus in, volutpat luctus magna. Cras facilisis odio sed sem maximus ullamcorper.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    Unknown content - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nisi arcu, convallis sed luctus in, volutpat luctus magna. Cras facilisis odio sed sem maximus ullamcorper. Donec laoreet vulputate suscipit. Proin rutrum elit eu dui ultricies
    auctor sit amet pharetra tortor. Donec feugiat iaculis ex id cursus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Donec viverra dolor eget ligula semper vestibulum. Phasellus dictum nulla quis lectus congue,
    sit amet pulvinar neque volutpat. Duis finibus sapien quis lorem suscipit, et luctus erat rutrum. Integer accumsan ipsum nec felis ultrices finibus. Integer at tincidunt orci. In tempus sollicitudin velit, sed dignissim ligula maximus ac.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want the div to completely cover the other two div's?

Comment: I am not clear what the final result should be. Could you describe more exactly what ‘stack over’ means.

Comment: I want to have the exact result I presented in the snippet, but with flexible content, without using JavaScript to control the paddings of 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

As you want items to be placed with space for their content we cannot have the inner (green) div positioned absolute.

This snippet has the first second and third divs just one below the other as standard. The first and third have their red and blue backgrounds respectively.

The second has a linear-gradient background, half red, half blue.

This snippet uses flex to position the texts centrally within each div but of course you can remove that if required.

```css
.stacked {
  color: #fff
}

.stacked .first,
.stacked .third {
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.stacked .first {
  background: red;
}

.stacked .third {
  background: blue;
}

.stacked .second {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red 0 50%, blue 50% 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.stacked .second>div {
  max-width: 50%;
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stacked">
  <div class="first">
    Unknown content - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nisi arcu, convallis sed luctus in, volutpat luctus magna. Cras facilisis odio sed sem maximus ullamcorper. Donec laoreet vulputate suscipit. Proin rutrum elit eu dui ultricies
    auctor sit amet pharetra tortor. Donec feugiat iaculis ex id cursus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Donec viverra dolor eget ligula semper vestibulum. Phasellus dictum nulla quis lectus congue,
    sit amet pulvinar neque volutpat. Duis finibus sapien quis lorem suscipit, et luctus erat rutrum. Integer accumsan ipsum nec felis ultrices finibus. Integer at tincidunt orci. In tempus sollicitudin velit, sed dignissim ligula maximus ac.
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <div>
      Unknown content - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nisi arcu, convallis sed luctus in, volutpat luctus magna. Cras facilisis odio sed sem maximus ullamcorper.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="third">
    Unknown content - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nisi arcu, convallis sed luctus in, volutpat luctus magna. Cras facilisis odio sed sem maximus ullamcorper. Donec laoreet vulputate suscipit. Proin rutrum elit eu dui ultricies
    auctor sit amet pharetra tortor. Donec feugiat iaculis ex id cursus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Donec viverra dolor eget ligula semper vestibulum. Phasellus dictum nulla quis lectus congue,
    sit amet pulvinar neque volutpat. Duis finibus sapien quis lorem suscipit, et luctus erat rutrum. Integer accumsan ipsum nec felis ultrices finibus. Integer at tincidunt orci. In tempus sollicitudin velit, sed dignissim ligula maximus ac.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would have to be absolute, since the linear gradient works in this scenario, but not in real life. I'll use JavaScript to apply padding to 1 and 3 (50% of the height of 2). Thanks, though, your solution is pretty smart

Comment: That's interesting - in what way does not it not work - could you give an example?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Raven0us/pen/dyKYWKo - assume all content varies (it's not just colours), and 1 and 3 actually meet, 2 can't be the glue between them. It's easy to do this with JavaScript by adding padding-bottom to 1, padding-top to 3 and negative margins on Y axis for 2. All the values would represent 50% of the height of 2.

Comment: What do you want it to look like when the background images are actual images? If the first and third divs were exactly joined what should the images look like? I assume the could be different images?

Comment: Consider divs with background image and text within them (the text is there to point out the importance of spacing). Yes, everything should be different, 2 needs to get out of context with 50% of its height over 1 and 50% of its height over 3. I want to reach my initial snippet with absolute positioning without having to calculate paddings for 1 and 3 via JavaScript. It's cool, thanks for the help